# nvidia-smi - “no devices were found” - ubuntu 22.04.3 with my Quadro P620

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I’m having issues with nvidia-smi saying no devices found.

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP107GL [Quadro P620]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:13:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=64
       resources: irq:16 memory:fc000000-fcffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e4000000-e5ffffff ioport:5000(size=128)
```

I’ve purged my drivers and I believe I’ve installed the latest headless driver:

```
$ find /usr/lib/modules -name nvidia.ko -exec modinfo {} \;
filename:       /usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-86-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
firmware:       nvidia/535.113.01/gsp_tu10x.bin
firmware:       nvidia/535.113.01/gsp_ga10x.bin
alias:          char-major-195-*
version:        535.113.01
```

Been banging my head against my desk for a couple days on this. Thanks for any help!

My nvidia bug report log for context

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/dtingruxfltjdsbqcoqk0/nvidia-bug-report.log?rlkey=hulukbbvwm88pfia6gzivimfy&dl=0

Comment: You might try installing the hwe packages to get the 6.2 kernel.  I haven't run a 5.15 in awhile, but have no problems with the 535 driver series.